# Why do people name their files index.html?

Tags: html

I have seen a lot of people been using that file name for their HTML files. I wonder why? I'm kind of new to HTML, I haven't learned much, but when I name my HTML files, I name them whatever I want. When I have been searching up examples of HTML, I have found they name it index.html. Why?

Comment: Apache returns `index.html` by default if you request a directory. Not sure if they did this because it was common or vice versa. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have seen a lot of people been using that file name for their HTML files

You would typically use that name for one of your page, and it would usually be the home page.

When you arrive a website, for example `www.website.com`, you're not pointing to a file (like you would be if you typed `www.website.com/about.html`), you're pointing to a directory listing of all the files.

The webserver will try to serve a file, typically called `index.html` or `index.php` by default, but it could be something different, and it's configurable by editing your webserver's config files.

If the server doesn't find any file to serve (because you didn't include an `index.html` file or because you renamed it without editing the server's config) you will see a listing of the files, which is rarely the desired behavior, especially at the root of a website.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the contents of index.html will be returned when just the directory is requested.

e.g. http://example.com/index.html is returned for a request for http://example.com

This is merely convention and is usually configurable.

Comment: ...because this is how the server is set up. It's not necessary, it's just standard.

Comment: Agreed (that is why I said generally).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take: It was likely named 'index' in the original internet because it is the 'indexing page' that directs to the sub pages, and you would go back to the index page to go to another page. This was before images and search engines. Later it got more advanced with a menu on all pages. This is how I remember it, but it's a long time ago.

https://twitter.com/PresidentUSW1/status/1442236777293496325?s=20

Answer (score 0):

The default landing page of many Web servers defaults to index.html or default.htm and either way it's simply a  start page. It's not necessary at all.