# MAMP Installation HTML PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mamp-pro

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MbQl.png)This is my first post here and i'm looking for getting some help.

I have recently taken courses in HTML/CSS/JavaScript and I feel pretty comfortable in that. Now i'm getting into PHP, and noticed that i need a localhost. I downloaded MAMP, added my website files to the htdocs but I cannot find my index.html in the localhost.

This is what I put in the browser: localhost/htdocs/web-development/Portfolio/index.html

What i'm trying to do is to preview my website and try my registration form which is done with html/css/javascript and php/phpmyadmin.

Even though I can understand and code HTML/CSS/JavaScript and still fairly new to programming so let me know if I explained it a bit messy.

I'm using Atom for coding.

Lukas

Comment: MAMP typically operates on port 8888 so to access the site in your htdocs folder you would use `http://localhost:8888/web-development/Portfolio/index.html`

Comment: Thanks cole, I did exactly this but it just says URL not found... hmm

Comment: You could try to put a file named `index.php` directly under the `htdocs/` folder. Next you visit `http://localhost:8888` and see if something changed. As soon as you find the place for that index.php file which serves the root of your localhost, the rest should become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration for `MAMP` uses ports `8888` and `8889`, and `7888`, you can see the default port in controle panel under ports

http://localhost:{port number}/{project folder}/index.html -> ( if write php file this could be index.php)

`htdocs` represents web root that you no need to use in url

Comment: Hi, yes tried that as well. I also added a index.html file only in the htdocs. I did this http://localhost:8888/index.html - didn't work

Comment: Also, http://localhost:8888/htdocs/index.html - didn't work either... :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image, your index.html file is in your forms folder, so you have two options:

1. Move your index.html into your portfolio file and have the server automatically serve it when the address localhost/htdocs/web-development/Portfolio is requested.
2. Change your URL route to localhost/htdocs/web-development/iPortfolio/forms/index.html

The first would be more in keeping with standards - the server will search for an index.html/php file in the route of a website, which is why people generally use this file for their homepage, as noted here [Why do people name their files index.html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408259/why-do-people-name-their-files-index-html)