# What is home.html? Difference between home and index?

Tags: html

I'm taking a backend course that just started today, and everything in that field is new to me. Our teacher told us "home.html" was the first file the server targeted when someone entered our website. That home.html was like index.html, but for the back end (meaning index.html was for the frontend) I guess my final question is, is that correct? Is there a difference between index.html and home.html?

I searched "home.html" , "index.html vs home.html", define "home.html", "home" +".html", backend "home.html" etc. But I didn't get a definitive answer. The only information I got (that confused me even more) is that it's preferred to name our homepage index.html over home.html.

Comment: AFAIK it's just a convention. index doesn't show up on URL as it's expected to be the landing page of a website. Many frameworks and systems that work with websites look for that file by default... there's some discussions around, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408259/why-do-people-name-their-files-index-html, https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-default-html-file-called-index-html ...

Comment: They're just file names. Web servers can typically be configured to serve any filename as the directory index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many webservers, such as Apache and Nginx have a convention that if you request a URL that maps to a directory on the server, they will look for a file called `index.html` and serve that if it exists.

This is configurable and the web browser is completely unaware this is happening.

Usually this is configured to look for `index.html`. It's possible that there were webservers that defaulted to `home.html`, but I'm not aware of it.

Neither are these are standard, it's just a convention and doesn't apply for many application-style webservers like Node. For Node, there's not by default a correlation between a URL path and a filesystem path.

Similarly the convention for PHP sites was to look for `index.php` instead if a URL was hit that maps to a directory.

So if your teacher told you exactly as you've written it, I would guess that your teacher doesn't fully understand this. However, something might have been lost in translation.

Comment: FYI the [Express static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) defaults to `index.html` so it does apply somewhat to Node (in the context of serving files / directories)

Comment: @Phil sure, anyone can do something that exhibits this behavior, but it's not default.

Answer (score -1):

I think the only difference is that **index.html** is usually the default landing page, meaning that when a user go to [www.yourwebsite.com](http://www.yourwebsite.com) without adding /home.html or /index.html (or anything), they will be directed to [www.yourwebsite.com/index.html](http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, there are no differences in naming your file `home.html` or `index.html`. They're just names for an HTML file, however, it is true that it's the *first thing* someone sees in the frontend when entering a webpage.